# When to rationalize to repair continuity, and why does it work?

Tags: limits, functions, continuity, limits-without-lhopital, symbolic-computation

I was working on a question out a GRE math prep book:

"Find the inverse of $f(x) = \frac{x}{1-x^2}$ that works for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ where $f$ is defined over $(-1,1)$"

(works meaning is well defined I'm guessing).

So the process is very routine for any precalculus student, we solve

$$ x = \frac{f^{-1}}{1 - f^{{-1}^2}} \rightarrow f^{-1} = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1 + 4x^2}}{2x}$$

And then observing the range of the two branches, versus the domain of our problem $(-1,1)$ we conclude that

$$ f^{-1} = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{1 + 4x^2}}{2x}$$

But this is where things get weird. So this is defined for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ except $x= 0$ where it is undefined but has a well defined limit point.

Now the book, very mechanically summarizes "whenever this happens, rationalize the numerator" without explanation, and sure enough they do that and arrive at an algebraically equivalent

$$ f^{-1} = \frac{2x}{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4x^2}}$$

Which is indeed "obviously" well defined for $x=0$. So here's my question:

Given a function $F(x)$ expressed as $S(x)$ (so S refers to the actual form of the function written down, where $F$ is the idea of the function itself, independent of how its written) where $S(x)$ has some collection of points $\omega_1 ... \omega_r$ such that $S(\omega_i)$ is undefined BUT $\lim_{x \rightarrow \omega_i} S(x)$ is well defined, how do we algorithmically find the transformation of $T$ $S(x)$ so that this limit becomes "obvious" (meaning the function algebraically simplifies to the desired value at that $\omega_i$). This is in effect a generalization of the question "how did you (the book) know to normalize the numerator in the first place"

### Work so far:

So we can look at the space of all algebraic expressions in a single variable $x$ as a starting point, let us consider $\mathbb{C}[x]$. Now over this space of expresison we have "symbolic" transformations $T$ with the property $a = T(a)$. And the question then is, given some algebraic expression $\tau$, how to find a $T$ such that $T(\tau)$ is not undefined at any point, where it's limit exists.

The problem I run into after quantifying this approach is that it's not clear to me how to enumerate through the space of all $T$, but my goal is to show that the $T$ that is "rationalize the numerator" can be derived as the optimal transformation for this particular example of $S = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{1 + 4x^2}}{2x}$

Comment: Do you know of an example of this phenomenon that does not involve rationalizing? What kind of a mathematical object is $S$? Perhaps a formal expression built from variables and some fixed set of operations and allowed functions.

Comment: I don't off the top of my head, but like I can imagine an example where say we have $S = a + b$, and a needs to rationalized in numerator, b rationalized in denominator, then added together and the entire thing rationalized in numerator. Say you were given $S$, how could one derive that " a needs to rationalized in numerator, b rationalized in denominator, then added together and the entire thing rationalized in numerator. " is the necessary transform to lift the limit points to becoming well defined.

Answer (score 0):

$f^{-1}$ is actually defined at $0$, and $f^{-1}(0) = f^{-1}(f(0)) = 0$. The problem is that you arrived at the expression of $f^{-1}$ under the (implicit) assumption that $y \neq 0$. In fact, $$y = f(x) = \frac{x}{1 - x^2} \iff yx^2 - y+ x = 0$$

This is a quadratic equation in $x$ iff $y \neq 0$, so the obtained expression is valid only when $y \neq 0$. If $y = 0$, then $x = 0$ and we get $f^{-1}(0) = 0$. Otherwise, we get that formula. It is then possible to simplify the expression of $f^{-1}$ and get one that is valid for all values.

**P.S.** I did not read the rest of the question, but I thought that it would be useful to point out what went wrong.

Comment: "It is then possible to simplify the expression of $f^{-1}$ and get one that is valid for all values." this is the part where I get a bit lost. How do we know this is possible? And even if we did have an oracle for that, given some piecewise collection of functions, how do we easily build an expression which passes through these, while itself being a well behaved algebraic expression, the book doesn't bother to question why "rationalize the numerator" works.

Comment: For example if we consider piece wise, my derived answer and $f^{-1}(0) = 12$ then we know that we are indeed screwed. There isn't a well behaved algebraic function that is going to behave that way, only for $f^{-1}(0) = 0$ does it work out. But knowing that, still doesn't make it rigorously clear how to go form $\frac{-1 + \sqrt{1 + 4x^2}}{2x} \rightarrow \frac{2x}{1 + \sqrt{1 + 4x^2}}$. We might as well have considered: $1 + \frac{-1 + \sqrt{1 + 4x^2}}{2x}  - 1$. How did we derive THAT PARTICLUAR, re-shuffling of expresisons?

Comment: We certainly didn't use an algorithm to decide to rationalize. Rationalizing radical expressions is wisdom that has been passed down through the mathematical generations. I am not familiar with the history and origins of the practice. If you want an algorithm for rationalizing an arbitrary radical expression, then you want to invoke Galois theory. (One multiplies something by its Galois conjugates to get a "simpler" something.)

Comment: "Rationalizing the numerator" is actually a form of multiplying by $\dfrac{a}{a}$, which is equal to $1$, except at one point. If $a$ occurs in the denominator of the expression we multiply it appears we have "miraculously" avoided an "exceptional point", which isn't quite true. In general, functions involving quotients that have a "removable discontinuity" when the denominator is zero, can often be recast as the "limit function" by some variation of this technique. There isn't, to my knowledge, a "one size fits all" technique that always works, one learns  various "tricks" from experience.

Answer (score 0):

as you go solving for $f^{-1}$

if $y = f^{-1}$ then:

$X = \frac {y}{1-y^2}\\
xy^2 + x - y = 0$

Now here you divided through by $x$ in order to apply the quadratic formula.  But in so doing, you have obliterated $x = 0$ and must make a note to yourself to return to this before you are complete.

$y = \dfrac{-1+\sqrt{1+4x^2}}{2x} \text { if } x\ne 0$, or $x = 0$

Comment: I see, but the "make a note to yourself" is the key, when we return how does one know how to symbolically re-arrange the terms (in this case rationalize the numerator) to fix this problem? Is there a way I could derive that? Say I give you some arbitrarily complex algebraic expression, which requires many rationalizations, introducing a +1, -1 combination at a spot ,etc... , how could we determine these transformations?

Comment: you could write a piece-wise function and it would be equally valid.  Rationalizing the numerator is just a different way of representing the same function.

Comment: Yea but do you see why that is odd. We have two different ways of talking about the same function $S_1, S_2$, yet one is well defined at these "limit points" while the other isn't. And so my question is given an $S_2$, how do I find the syntactic transformation (such as normalizing the numerator, which by itself doesn't CHANGE the function at all), so that I get an expression $S_1$ which is defined everywhere